# I want to Create Car object using Vehicle class ( i.e Vehicle c = new Car() ), and insert it into the list correctly

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I created a Car object using Vehicle class ( i.e Vehicle c = new Car() ), but my problem is how I will insert it into the list then Prompt the user to enter details for this object after the insertion in the list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestCar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Car>list=new ArrayList<Car>();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        list.add(new Car());
         list.add(new Car("Mitsubishi",1993,5,"Pajero"));

        System.out.println("Enter Brand");
        String Brand=in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Year");
        int Year=in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Engine size");
        double Enginesize=in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Model");
        String Model=in.nextLine();

        list.get(0).setBrand(Brand);
        list.get(0).setYear(Year);
        list.get(0).setEngineSize(Enginesize);
        list.get(0).setModel(Model);

        Veichle c = new Car(Brand, Year, Enginesize,Model); // Creating a   new object
        list.add(c); // This add will be wrong because cuz 
                     //it will tell me to change type c to car
                     // so whats the correct add?

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the constructor of `Car` class? is it `public Car(String brand, int year, double engineSize, String model)` or also you have `public Car()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created an `ArrayList<Car>` - you can *only* add elements to that list that the compiler *knows* to be cars. So you could use:

```
list.add((Car) c);
```

or more simply, just declare the type of `c` to be `Car` to start with:

```
Car c = new Car(...);
```

Getting values *out* of the list, you're fine to use `Vehicle`, because every `Car` is a `Vehicle`:

```
Vehicle vehicle = list.get(0);
```

Alternatively, you could change your `list` variable to:

```
List<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
```

Or equivalently:

```
List<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

(Note that it's generally preferrably to use the interface (`List` in this case) for the variable type, even though you need to specify a concrete class (`ArrayList` here) to create an instance.)

At this point, however, your code that modifies the brand etc wouldn't work if `setBrand` is only defined on `Car`, not vehicle - because `list.get(0)` would only return a `Vehicle`. You could potentially use:

```
Car firstVehicle = (Car) list.get(0);
```

... but obviously that would fail (at execution-time) if your list *actually* contained a non-Car vehicle.

**Fundamentally, you need to decide whether your list should be able to contain *any* vehicle, or only cars.**

As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you start following Java naming conventions - use `camelCase` for your local variables (`year`, `brand` etc.)

Comment: Okay so I wrote `Veichle c = new Car();` Then `list.add((Car) c);` but then there is a problem with `Vehicle vehicle = list.get(0);` in which it tells me Veichle cant be resolved to a type

Comment: @Memo: You have a typo - `Veichle` isn't `Vehicle`. It looks like your class is *currently* called `Veichle`, but you should rename it to `Vehicle`.

Comment: oh okay, one last question '`Vehicle vehicle = list.get(0)` when i print it using `for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
   System.out.println(list.get(i));` will not prompt the user to enter any values.. why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You should have created it as:

```
List<Vehicle>list=new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
```

Two point to observe:

1. Always program to interface.
2. A car is always a vehicle but reverse is not always true.

Also IMO the following code is really ugly:

```
list.get(0).setBrand(Brand);
list.get(0).setYear(Year);
list.get(0).setEngineSize(Enginesize);
list.get(0).setModel(Model);
```

Comment: @Jon My bad. Corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this.

```
List<vehicle> list = new new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
```

after doing this, you can add vehicle-type, and objects of all its sub-classes  in list

lets suppose:

```
    class Vehicle {
     //some implmentation
    }

    class Car extends Vehicle {
     //some implementation
    }

    class Truck extends Vehicle {
     // some implementation
    }

    class Main{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
      Car car = new Car();
      Truck truck = new Truck();
      list.add(car);
     list.add(truck)
     // you need to check the instance and cast with its appropriate class. 
      Vehicle obj = list.get(1);
      Car car1 = null;
if(obj instanceOf Car){
       car1 = (Car) obj;
}



    }
    }
```

or you can simply do this, before adding in list cast your polymorphic object with car. like this.

```
List.add((Car) car);
```

Comment: what is list.get(i) from where I will get the i?